# Is this manipulation of a sequence of linear operators legal?

Tags: real-analysis

I am independently studying Royden's Analysis and there is one manipulation of linear operators that I am unsure if I can do. In my string of inequalities, I'm not sure if I can make the jump from $\|T_n(u_n) - T(u)\|$ to $\|(T_n - T)(u_n - u)\|$.

Royden does state that we can say: $\|T_n(u) - T_m(u)\| = \|(T_n - T_m)u\|$. The difference is that $T_n$ and $T_m$ belong to the same sequence, so I wasn't sure if that was different. Here is what I have:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, because $(T_n-T)(u_n-u)=T_n(u_n-u) - T(u_n - u)=T_n(u_n) - T_n(u) - T(u_n) + T(u)$ which has no reason a priori to be equals to $T_n(u_n) - T(u)$. In this kind of exercise, a very common method is to introduce a "middle point", that you can both compare to $T_n(u_n)$ and $T(u)$. For example, here :

$||T_n(u_n) - T(u)|| = ||T_n(u_n) - T(u_n) + T(u_n) - T(u)|| \leq ||(T_n-T)(u_n)|| + ||T(u_n-u)||$

I let you finish the proof

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not legal. Because these are linear, $(T_n-T)(u_n-u) = T_n(u_n) - T_n(u) - T(u_n) + T(u)$. Presumably this is not what you were going for.

Perhaps more helpful is $$\begin{align}\|T_n(u_n)-T(u)\| & = \|T_n(u_n)-T(u_n)+T(u_n)-T(u)\| \\ & \leq \|T_n(u_n)-T(u_n)\| + \|T(u_n)-T(u)\|\end{align}$$This should do the trick for you :)